# Oracle - SQL with recursive WHERE clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that stores the hierarchy of workgroups in our organization.  It looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE WORKGROUPS  ( 
    WORKGROUPID         NUMBER NULL,
    NAME                VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    PARENTWORKGROUPID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    WORKGROUPLEVEL      CHAR(1) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT WORKGROUPS_PK PRIMARY KEY(WORKGROUPID)
)
```

For example, there might be three levels of workgroups deep:

```
ID 1 - Sales (PARENTWORKGROUPID = 0)
ID 2 - Business Sales (PARENTWORKGROUPID = 1)
ID 3 - West Coast B2B (PARENTWORKGROUPID = 2)
```

So 3's parent is 2, 2's parent is 1, and 1 is a top level workgroup with no parent, so we use 0.

Now we have a TASKS table.  Each TASKS row has a WORKGROUPID column that points to a WORKGROUPID in the WORKGROUPS table.

I need to write a query that returns all TASKS that are under a given top-level workgroup, such as everything under Sales (which, in the example above, could be WORKGROUPIDs 1, 2 or 3.  Basically, it's a recursive query.

I can think of some ways to do this using a LEFT JOIN for to check each level, but I'd rather stay away from solutions that hard-code in the number of levels since the database is designed to allow any number of tiers.  Any other solution I can think of involves changing the table schema, which I can't do at the moment.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle seems to have its own version of recursion (I use SQL Server and DB2, which use Common Table Expressions to power recursion), but I think this should possibly get what you want:

```
WITH WGS (
    WORKGROUPID,
    NAME
) AS (
    SELECT WORKGROUPID,
        NAME
    FROM WORKGROUPS
    START WITH WORKGROUPID = :top-lev-dept
    CONNECT BY WORKGROUPID = PRIOR PARENTWORKGROUPID
)

SELECT DISTINCT T.*
FROM TASKS
INNER JOIN WGS W
    ON (T.WORKGROUPID = W.WORKGROUPID)
```

You'd obviously change `:top-lev-dept` to the department you're searching for.

If that's not it, you might check out [the Oracle reference page on Hierarchical Queries](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm).  That might get you started in the right direction...

Comment: Awesome, yea it looks like this "connect by" is the key..  I will do more research on that topic and go from there - thanks for the pointer!

Comment: This basically ended up being almost exactly what I did.  I tried to use CONNECT_BY_ROOT but it didn't seem to work with the way I was joining stuff in.  So I used the CTE instead, and updated my view to return the "root" workgroup for all the rows.  Now, I can just select from that view and query for specific root workgroups, easy and pie.

Answer (score 2):

[Starting with Oracle 11gR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/wnsql.htm#sthref6), the ANSI recursive WITH syntax is supported, and is an alternative to START WITH/CONNECT BY:

```
WITH wgs ( workgroupid, name ) AS
(
    SELECT workgroupid, name FROM workgroups WHERE workgroupid = :top-lev-dept
     UNION ALL
    SELECT w.workgroupid, w.name FROM workgroups w, wgs WHERE parentworkgroupid = wgs.workgroupid
)
SELECT ...
```

The key here is:

```
WITH view (column_definition) AS
(
    SELECT root rows
     UNION ALL
    SELECT sub rows FROM table JOIN view ON recursion condition
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I decided to go with the `START WITH/CONNECT BY` method with a CTE, mainly to learn something new and also it required minimal changes to the view I was getting this data from.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to investigate the `START WITH/CONNECT BY` syntax.

Something like:

```
select * from workgroups
start with parentworkgroupid = 0
connect by prior workgroupid = parentworkgroupid;
```

Totally untested, but I think it will get you started.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent, I think this at least gets me heading in the right direction.  Thanks!